# Unity ignoring type mapping in app.config

Tags: unity-container

I have the following settings in the appropriate sections of my app.config:

```
<alias alias="resourceManager" 
       type="Infrastructure.Dictionary.Localization.IResourceManager, Infrastructure.Dictionary" />

<register type="resourceManager"
          mapTo="Infrastructure.Dictionary.Localization.LocalizeDictionaryWrapper, Infrastructure.Dictionary" 
          name="Default">
    <lifetime type="singleton" />        
</register>
```

When I call container.Resolve(NonLocalizedStrings.Default);

I get the following exception:

> "Resolution of the dependency failed, type =
>   "Infrastructure.Dictionary.Localization.IResourceManager", name =
>   "Default".Exception occurred while: while
>   resolving.
>   Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current
>   type, Infrastructure.Dictionary.Localization.IResourceManager, is an
>   interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type
>   mapping?
>   At the time of the exception, the container was:
>   Resolving Infrastructure.Dictionary.Localization.IResourceManager,Default"

Why is Unity ignoring my mapping?

Comment: If you start to use <alias>, probably you should also use <namespace> and <assembly> to further simplify the file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad.  I am attempting to resolve a type before Unity has had the chance to configure its container.